# getting specific user information from an array

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
function returnAge(PlayerId){
    var data = [
        {name : 'jack', isPlayer: true, games:[{id:343, age:12}, {id:3422, age :132}]},
        { id :2 , name : 'king'},
        {id: 145,   name: 'james'}
    ]


    let filteredData= data.filter(item=>item.isPlayer)
    let itemData = filteredData[0].games.find(game=>game.id===PlayerId)

    return itemData
}

console.log(returnAge(343))
```

The function returns the information of a user with particular Id if the user is a player. I used a filter and then used a find to get the information based on the filtered data.I am looking for a better way of doing this by using Reduce/destructor or any other JavaScript feature. Kindly appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: If your objective is to learn new methodologies, maybe look at e.g. lenses: https://medium.com/javascript-inside/an-introduction-into-lenses-in-javascript-e494948d1ea5

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to over complicate the solution with those functions, use a simple `for-loop` along with the function `find`.

*The function `filter`is not suitable because will loop the whole set of elements.*

```js
function returnAge(PlayerId) {
  var data = [{      name: 'jack',      isPlayer: true,      games: [{        id: 343,        age: 12      }, {        id: 3422,        age: 132      }]    },    {      id: 2,      name: 'king'    },    {      id: 145,      name: 'james'    }  ]

  for (var item of data) if (item.isPlayer) return item.games.find(g => g.id === PlayerId);
}

console.log(returnAge(343))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use function `find`

```js
function returnAge(PlayerId){
    var data = [
        {name: 'jack', isPlayer: true, games:[{id:343, age:12}, {id:3422, age :132}]},
        {id: 2, name: 'king'},
        {id: 145, name: 'james'}
    ]

    return data.find(item=>item.isPlayer).games.find(game=>game.id===PlayerId)
}

console.log(returnAge(343))
```